# Get route error in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get an error `Cannot Get /`. this is my folder structure

[image]

This is the route.js file:

```
//route.js

'use strict';

var app = require('../../config/express');

var router = app.Router();

/* Get Home Controller */
var homeController = require('../controllers/index');

router.get('/index', homeController.index); //it isn't recognized

app.use('/', router);
```

---

```
'use strict';

/*
 *  GET /
 *  Home Page
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    'pageTitle': 'Express page'
  });
};
```

---

```
'use strict';

/* Import Express module */
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/* Import env config parameters */
var settings = require('./env/settings');

/* Create express server */
var app = express();

/* Settings Application */
app.set('port', settings.port);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

module.exports = app;
```

I know that it is a problem on routing but I have tried to fix it

Comment: Instead of `app.use('/', router);` try `app.use(router);`.

Comment: Just do it but it still doesn't work

Comment: I rarely use Jade, but do you have `/frontend/views/index.html` file, isn't that what you're referencing ?

Comment: I have index.jade not index.html

Comment: Then it's probably ok, I'm used to EJS which uses .html

Comment: You're exporting `app`, whereas you should probably be exporting `express` if you want to call the `Router` method. At the moment, `app.Router()` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`Cannot Get /` is exactly what is says. You have not defined any routes that match that path. You have defined `/index`, but not `/`, and they are two different URLs. `index.html`-style behavior is not provided by Express in routes. It is available with the static-file middleware if you want it though.

So change it to:

```
router.get('/', homeController.index);
```

or if you also want `/index` to work, just do both:

```
router.get('/', homeController.index);
router.get('/index', homeController.index);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work...I suppose the problem is about what Ben Fortune says

Comment: Hmm, that also looks wrong, but that should be causing your script to throw and crash before it even starts. Are you sure the code you posted is the code that you're running?